# How to check the smaller bitmap chunks sequence with the given bitmap

Tags: android

I have bitmap image divided into chunks randomly, now I need to find the correct order of the bitmap. how do I do that ?

My program is like a picture puzzle so once u have completed arranging the chunks of images I need to find wether the smaller bitmaps are arranged in correct sequence to check whether the user has finished the puzzle.

Comment: In chunk mechanism assign `index=bitmapChunk` and after that check id's right sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a holder class for each chunk, and then when it is randomly broken up, remember the original position? assuming that they are organized into rows and columns (in any random order) then when you break the image up, store it in a class like this:

```
class Chunk
{
    public Bitmap bitmapChunk;

    public int correctPositionX;
    public int correctPositionY;

    public int currentPositionX;
    public int currentPositionY;

    public boolean isInCorrectPosition()
    {
        if (currentPositionX == correctPositionX && currentPositionY == correctPositionY)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Regardless though, just store the information when you cut it up, of where it needs to be to be correct.

You could also assign a left to right sequence id, so that it looks like this

```
123
456
789
```

and then just check to make sure the sequence is correct. For example this would be incorrect:

```
285
976
431
```

or like I said earlier do a table

```
[0,0][1,0][2,0]
[0,1][1,1][2,1]
[0,2][1,2][2,2]
```